# How to escape special characters in the function read.table in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, special-characters, read.table

I'm trying to extract a data frame in R of the Carnegie Mellon University Pronouncing Dictionary.
This works fine to get a data frame :

```
url <- "http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/cmudict/cmudict-0.7b"
library(RCurl)
answer <- RCurl::getURL(url)
dictionary <- as.vector(unlist(strsplit(answer, "\n")))
dictionary <- gsub("  ", "\t", dictionary)
dictionary.df <- read.table(text = dictionary, header=FALSE, skip =150, sep = "\t")
```

But the content of the dictionary is after line 54 so the value for the skip parameter should be "54".
It seems special characters contained in lines 54 to 150 cause the following errors.

For instance :

```
> dictionary.df <- read.table(text = dictionary, header=FALSE, skip =54, sep = "\t")
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 2 elements


> dictionary.df <- read.table(text = dictionary, header=FALSE, skip =120, sep = "\t")
Warning messages:
1: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  Fin de fichier (EOF) dans une chaîne de caractères entre guillements
2: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  le nombre d'objets lus n'est pas un multiple du nombre de colonnes
```

Is there a quick way to avoid this errors escaping characters?

Thank you very much for your help !

Ludovic

Answer (score 2):

`fread` from the **data.table** package seems appropriate here.

```
library(data.table)

dt_dic <- fread(url, skip=56, sep=NULL, header = FALSE, col.names="Item")

dt_dic[, c("Item", "Pronunciation") := tstrsplit(Item, "  ")]
dt_dic
                      Item                            Pronunciation
     1: !EXCLAMATION-POINT EH2 K S K L AH0 M EY1 SH AH0 N P OY2 N T
     2:       "CLOSE-QUOTE                      K L OW1 Z K W OW1 T
     3:      "DOUBLE-QUOTE                  D AH1 B AH0 L K W OW1 T
     4:      "END-OF-QUOTE                  EH1 N D AH0 V K W OW1 T
     5:         "END-QUOTE                        EH1 N D K W OW1 T
    ---                                                            
133850:             {BRACE                                B R EY1 S
133851:        {LEFT-BRACE                      L EH1 F T B R EY1 S
133852:        {OPEN-BRACE                    OW1 P EH0 N B R EY1 S
133853:       }CLOSE-BRACE                      K L OW1 Z B R EY1 S
133854:       }RIGHT-BRACE                        R AY1 T B R EY1 S
```

Comment: Thank you very much Edward !

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bit of an x/y problem.

You already have the data in memory in the character vector `dictionary`, and you want to turn this into a data frame. You are trying to use `read.table` to do this, and stuck because `read.table` is struggling with some of the special characters in the vector. Instead of trying to figure out a way to force `read.table` to do the job, why not just split the strings at the double spaces and bind them together into a data frame?

When I downloaded the file, the header takes up 56 rather than 54 lines, so we drop these, then call `strsplit` on the double spaces of the remaining lines, without having to first convert them to `\t` characters. Then we use `as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", ...))` on the resulting list to get our data frame.

Here's a reprex:

```r
url <- "http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/cmudict/cmudict-0.7b"
answer <- RCurl::getURL(url)
dictionary <- as.vector(unlist(strsplit(answer, "\n")))
dictionary.df <- strsplit(dictionary[-seq(56)], "  ")
dictionary.df <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", dictionary.df), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(dictionary.df) <- c("Item", "Pronunciation")
head(dictionary.df)
#>                 Item                            Pronunciation
#> 1 !EXCLAMATION-POINT EH2 K S K L AH0 M EY1 SH AH0 N P OY2 N T
#> 2       "CLOSE-QUOTE                      K L OW1 Z K W OW1 T
#> 3      "DOUBLE-QUOTE                  D AH1 B AH0 L K W OW1 T
#> 4      "END-OF-QUOTE                  EH1 N D AH0 V K W OW1 T
#> 5         "END-QUOTE                        EH1 N D K W OW1 T
#> 6         "IN-QUOTES                        IH1 N K W OW1 T S
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much Allan !

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to compare proposed solutions by computing time:

```
dic.url <- "http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/cmudict/cmudict-0.7b"

function1 <- function(dic.url){
  start_time <- Sys.time()
  library(data.table)
  dic <- fread(dic.url, skip=56, sep=NULL, header = FALSE, col.names="Item")
  dic[, c("Item", "Pronunciation") := tstrsplit(Item, "  ")]
  end_time <- Sys.time()
  time <- end_time - start_time
  print(time)
  return(dic)
  }

function2 <- function(dic.url){
  start_time <- Sys.time()
  answer <- RCurl::getURL(dic.url)
  dic <- as.vector(unlist(strsplit(answer, "\n")))
  dic <- strsplit(dic[-seq(56)], "  ")
  dic <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", dic), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  names(dic) <- c("Item", "Pronunciation")
  end_time <- Sys.time()
  time <- end_time - start_time
  print(time)
  return(dic)
  }

dic <- function1(dic.url)
dic <- function2(dic.url)
```

Some indications :

```
> dic <- function1(dic.url)
Time difference of 2.627239 secs

> dic <- function2(dic.url)
Time difference of 3.394491 secs
```